# How to get value from TextBox in TemplateField when value change by javascript c# asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

script(update value)

```
$("#txtPlanDate").datepicker();
```

---

design page

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPlanDate" ReadOnly="true" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PlanDate", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

---

code behind (get value)

```
protected void GridView1_OnRowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)

{TextBox txtPlanDate = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("txtPlanDate");}
```

Comment: Shouldn't $("#txtGenDate").datepicker(); be $("#txtPlanDate").datepicker();  ?

Comment: Thanks, but I have problem when get value in code behind,
because page not refresh when change value with java script.

Comment: You can force a postback in JavaScript using the __doPostBack function. This will mean you'll be able to get the value in your code behind. Here's more info about how to do it: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667531/doPostBack-function

Comment: Remove `Cells[5]`, without that also you can do `FindControl`. When you change the value of the `TextBox` why should it hit `RowUpdating` event? There will be separate events for that.

Comment: @SueSaya: Add `!IsPostBack` in your `Page_Load` event and inside that write you gridview data bind code, before your `onRowUpdating` event is fired `Page_Load` event  get executed and it resets your grid data. So, all client side changes gets lost.

Comment: I use ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "DoPostBack", "submit', '')", true); before TextBox txtPlanDate = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("txtPlanDate"); and add function submit() {
              form1.submit();
          } in javascript; It's work!!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have textbox inside gridview templatefield . Then You need something like this
`if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {
    TextBox txtPlanDate = (e.Row.FindControl("txtPlanDate") as TextBox);
   }`

It works OnRowDatabound event.Not tested OnRoUpdating event but it should work fine.